# I run bitcoind in linux centos server. but it give me error "sendto: Operation not permitted". why?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, linux

```
root@srv [~/public_html/server/bin]# ./bitcoind -daemon
```

Bitcoin server starting

```
root@srv [~/public_html/server/bin]# sendto: Operation not permitted
```

What is the problem?

Also, bitcoind didn't download the blockchain in my linux centos server.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely SELinux.

`~/public_html` is not the correct place to store binaries or even the bitcoin data directory.

Put the binaries in `~/bin/`

The data files should end up in `~/.bitcoin/` if you haven't changed the configuration. That should be okay.

If it still doesn't work you might need to run `restorecon -R ~/bin` to fix SELinux attributes.

Comment: `root/public_html/server/bin/ ` here is my bitcoind . and data file is  `'root/.bitcoin/` . what is the problem?? i run the command `restorecon -R ~/bin`. sitill same this.. pls give me some solution

Comment: public_html is for serving web pages, not for binaries. Put the bitcoin binaries in ~/bin/ . AFTER moving you may need to run restorecon.  Also don't run bitcoin (or anything) as root, create a new user and run bitcoin as that user. Once you have it working you probably want to set it up as a systemd service, which is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely to be a Firewall problem. 
The "sendto: operation not permitted" is the typical message you get from an iptables reject

i never run a full bitcoind myself but looking at the documentation you need port **tcp:8333** inbound and , i guess, at least **HTTP and HTTPS** outbound ...

check your firewall with

```
iptables -L -n
```

if the firewall is running, just to confirm you might try to stop the firewall and see if it fixes your problem.